# Why can't I get the hero image to show in my CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am a reasonably competent c# programmer, just starting to mess around with HTML and CSS etc.
I was playing around on *Neocities*, trying to set up a `background image` for my text and, well, absolutely nothing is showing despite my best efforts.

The html amd images are in the same directory (I know, I'll fix that later!).

Can anybody take a look at this code and point me in the right direction?

Best regards,

--*Rev*

EDIT: Good grief, thanks for all the notes & edits. Have added a sample of the html for the page below. It's quite a large page and I'm not completely comfortable with uploading the content here as it relates to a project I want to recruit artists for - I don't want to make the entirety of the page available just yet. Instead, I've grabbed some samples of typical paragraphs, etc.

Most of the comments within the text come from the Neocities boilerplate, which I haven't yet deleted.

Thanks for taking the time to look at this newbies work.

```css
/* CSS is how you can add style to your website, such as colors, fonts, and positioning of your
   HTML content. To learn how to do something, just try searching Google for questions like
   "how to change link color." */

a:link {
  color: #cc0000;
}

a:visited {
  color: #999999;
}

a:hover {
  color: #ff3300;
}

body {
  background-color: #323238;
  color: #648381;
  font-family: Verdana;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 640px;
  */
}

.hero-image {
  /* background-image: url(powerNode45Degrees01001RS.png); /* The image used */
  background-image: url("emotionalComp01.png");
  /* background-color: #323238; /* Used if the image is unavailable */
  /* height: 1024px; /* You must set a specified height */
  /* background-position: center center; /* Center the image */
  /* background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Do not repeat the image */
  /* background-size: cover; /* Resize the background image to cover the entire container */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Project Factotum Concept Artist Recruitment</title>
  <!-- The style.css file allows you to change the look of your web pages.
         If you include the next line in all your web pages, they will all share the same look.
         This makes it easier to make new pages for your site. -->
  <link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">

</head>
<!--<img src="powerNode45Degrees01001RS.png" />-->

<body>
  <img src="superSuperSuperSuperEarly3DSketch01.png" alt="A VERY early 3D concept" title="A VERY early 3D concept" />

  <h1>Generic Heading</h1>

  <p>I am an experienced game developer (C#/Unity/Blender/Photoshop/Krita) with multiple completed mobile projects for clients (can provide information on a number of them, am under NDA for others).</p>
  <p>While I’m a decent modeller, I don’t have the genius for design that this project demands - hence recruiting a 2D concept artist!</p>

  <h2 id="ARTISTREQUIREMENTS">ARTIST REQUIREMENTS</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>2D concept artist, potentially a generalist. 3D concepts are cool, but not essential.</li>
    <li>Artist should be able to collaborate using Skype / Discord / Gmail / Google Docs.</li>
    <li>Candidate must demonstrate a firm grasp of colour theory, composition, anatomy, working visual hierarchies, developing clear unique silhouettes.</li>
    <li>Ideally, artist will be willing to do rough paint-overs of environment screenshots to show designs in-situ.


      <li>Should be able to follow <a href="https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Assets_Naming_Convention">this naming convention</a></li>
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try to create a working snippet by adding your HTML, it will be easier to take a look and help !

Comment: The CSS looks fine, maybe try to remove the quotes in your background-image, but that shouldn't make a difference. Try posting your HTML, as Takit Isy suggested.

Comment: With your minimal css (and not seeing the HTML), I would say the issue is that a `div` with a background image does not expand unless there is content. In other words, the background image size has no effect on the container height or width. What happens if you uncomment the `height` property on the `.hero-image`?

Comment: Can we see the HTML?

Comment: The Best way the resolves HTML image or file is to use Inspect Element on your browser because it can be anything. 1- Make sure your image is resolvable by the browser, so check `http://localhost/emotionalComp01.png` on a new page to see that the image can display. 2- Inside inspect element, play in your css and change like `background-image: url("../emotionalComp01.png");`, if the directory you're serving the css is deeper than the directory of your image.

Comment: When I test it with a simple span `<span class="hero-image" style="display:inline-block;height:50px;width:100px;">HELLO WORLD</span>`, the background image displays.

Comment: You have a rogue closing comment '*/' at the end of your body css. Remove that. also double check the file name/path

Comment: @Rachel Gallen, have removed closing comment & double checked name/path, no change, thank you!

Comment: @KeitelDOG, Image is available, can display in normal html. holy cow, the span suggestion appears to have worked, image appears in test. Okay, now trying to get it running in BG...

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy, absolutely, have included sample above. If you really really really want to see the page, can link to it, but it's WIP and mainly intended only for a small group of 2D concept artists.

Comment: @disinfor , I'm afraid I don't have a div in the entire html and will be looking that up immediately. Have uncommented the height property to no affect on the page.

Comment: @TakitIsy and elveti, have added html sample above. Thank you for your patience, I'm certain I'm doing something stupid here.

Comment: Normally, when you use `.hero-image {...}` rule in css, then you must apply it with `<div class=".hero-image"><div>`, and make sure that the container have decent width and height to display part of the image. But I don't see anywhere you're applying the css rule. Make sure the bigger the image resolution is, the bigger the container size is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML has no mention of the hero-image class. That's the main problem. I added a surrounding div with a class of hero-image, and used a placeholder 'hero' image (wiki superman logo) to demonstrate the solution. The file path includes the domain name, folder, name of file. This may be shortened on your own hosting (to exclude the domain name, and begin with a backslash) but as you are just beginning, I recommend you use the full path

Also ensure the following:
-that the file is not corrupt
-that the filename is correctly spelled

Hope this helps

```css
a:link {
  color: #cc0000;
}

a:visited {
  color: #999999;
}

a:hover {
  color: #ff3300;
}

body {
  background-color: #323238;
  color: #648381;
  font-family: Verdana;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 640px;
  */
}

.hero-image {
  /* background-image: url(powerNode45Degrees01001RS.png); /* The image used */
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/e/ea/Superman_shield.svg/1200px-Superman_shield.svg.png");
  /* background-color: #323238; /* Used if the image is unavailable */
  /* height: 1024px; /* You must set a specified height */
  /* background-position: center center; /* Center the image */
  /* background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Do not repeat the image */
  background-size: contain; /* Resize the background image to cover the entire container */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Project Factotum Concept Artist Recruitment</title>
    <!-- The style.css file allows you to change the look of your web pages.
         If you include the next line in all your web pages, they will all share the same look.
         This makes it easier to make new pages for your site. -->
    <link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
  
  </head>
  <!--<img src="powerNode45Degrees01001RS.png" />-->
  <body>
  <div class="hero-image">
    <img src="superSuperSuperSuperEarly3DSketch01.png" alt="A VERY early 3D concept" title="A VERY early 3D concept" />
  
    <h1>Generic Heading</h1>

    <p>I am an experienced game developer (C#/Unity/Blender/Photoshop/Krita) with multiple completed mobile projects for clients (can provide information on a number of them, am under NDA for others).</p>
    <p>While I’m a decent modeller, I don’t have the genius for design that this project demands - hence recruiting a 2D concept artist!</p>

    <h2 id="ARTISTREQUIREMENTS">ARTIST REQUIREMENTS</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>2D concept artist, potentially a generalist. 3D concepts are cool, but not essential.</li>
      <li>Artist should be able to collaborate using Skype / Discord / Gmail / Google Docs.</li>
      <li>Candidate must demonstrate a firm grasp of colour theory, composition, anatomy, working visual hierarchies, developing clear unique silhouettes.</li>
      <li>Ideally, artist will be willing to do rough paint-overs of environment screenshots to show designs in-situ.
  

    <li>Should be able to follow <a href="https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Assets_Naming_Convention">this naming convention</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have created a class rule in css to display an image as a background of and element :

```
.hero-image {
  /* background-image: url(powerNode45Degrees01001RS.png); /* The image used */
  background-image: url("emotionalComp01.png");
  /* background-color: #323238; /* Used if the image is unavailable */
  /* height: 1024px; /* You must set a specified height */
  /* background-position: center center; /* Center the image */
  /* background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Do not repeat the image */
  /* background-size: cover; /* Resize the background image to cover the entire container */
}
```

Then you need to tell on which element or elements you need to apply this css rule with `class` attribute as `class="hero-image"`. Here you can apply it to `<p>` and `<ul>` elements like :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Project Factotum Concept Artist Recruitment</title>
    <!-- The style.css file allows you to change the look of your web pages.
         If you include the next line in all your web pages, they will all share the same look.
         This makes it easier to make new pages for your site. -->
    <link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">

  </head>
  <!--<img src="powerNode45Degrees01001RS.png" />-->
  <body>
    <img src="superSuperSuperSuperEarly3DSketch01.png" alt="A VERY early 3D concept" title="A VERY early 3D concept" />

    <h1>Generic Heading</h1>

    <p class="hero-image">I am an experienced game developer (C#/Unity/Blender/Photoshop/Krita) with multiple completed mobile projects for clients (can provide information on a number of them, am under NDA for others).</p>
    <p>While I’m a decent modeller, I don’t have the genius for design that this project demands - hence recruiting a 2D concept artist!</p>

    <h2 id="ARTISTREQUIREMENTS">ARTIST REQUIREMENTS</h2>
    <ul class="hero-image">
      <li>2D concept artist, potentially a generalist. 3D concepts are cool, but not essential.</li>
      <li>Artist should be able to collaborate using Skype / Discord / Gmail / Google Docs.</li>
      <li>Candidate must demonstrate a firm grasp of colour theory, composition, anatomy, working visual hierarchies, developing clear unique silhouettes.</li>
      <li>Ideally, artist will be willing to do rough paint-overs of environment screenshots to show designs in-situ.</li>


    <li>Should be able to follow <a href="https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Assets_Naming_Convention">this naming convention</a></li>
    </ul>

  </body>
</html>
```

And the background image shoud display in both the paragraph and the UL list.

Comment: Thank you, KeitelDOG. My intention is to place this image floating in the background, faintly visible against the background colour and glimpsed behind the text (behind both text and UL and outside of those areas). Honestly, you've provided me with a lot of info here to work with and research, however, so I'm tempted to mark this answer as correct. Will experiment and return...

Comment: Then you can just add a wrapper div as `<div id="main_wrapper" class="hero_image">...(all elements)...</div>` that will content all `img` `h1` `p` an `ul`.
And don't worry it's not about accepting a correct answer, it's about getting your problem solved. Check @Rachel Gallen answer codes to see if it does help you.

Comment: One of your li closing tag `</li>` was missing, so I added it.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS looks fine, there might be an issue in HTML. Did you add `id="hero-image"` in your div or `class="hero-image"` because if you added an ID the CSS should be like this:

`#hero-image {
  background-image: url("emotionalComp01.png");
}`

And if you added CLASS it should be like this:

`.hero-image {
  background-image: url("emotionalComp01.png");
}`

But if that is not the problem, you will need to post the html here.

Comment: You have class and ID swapped.

Comment: Good, but you misused ID selector with CLASS one.

Comment: Also it's reversed... For classes it's `.`, for ID it's `#`, not the opposite

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy I edited Jonathan's answer for CLASS and ID selector swapping. But this is not my answer. So my comments on the OP don't have anything to do with Jonathan and should not be reported in his answer, nor affecting his answer.

Comment: ...I have neither DIV nor CLASS, I fear that I am about to be laughed out of Stack Overflow. Researching...